# Could someone explian the DiffLib library?

Tags: python, difflib

According to the Python documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html , when I am comparing two sequences '+' is appended when the line is unique to sequence1 and '-' for sequence2. 
'? ' is appended when line is not present in either input sequence. What does this mean? Could someone explain me when a '?' is appended?

Comment: Good question.  There's an example in the documentation for [`ndiff`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) that returns lines with `'? ...'`

Answer (score 1):

On the same section of the doc you linked:

> Lines beginning with ‘?‘ attempt to guide the eye to intraline differences, and were not present in either input sequence.

It's solely for visualization purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There is some further explanation below the table you are referring to:

> Lines beginning with ‘?‘ attempt to guide the eye to intraline
>   differences, and were not present in either input sequence.

Which is not particularly clear, but means that the lines are merely *explantory*, and not part of the actual diff output. The example for [ndiff](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) makes this clearer:

```
>>> diff = ndiff('one\ntwo\nthree\n'.splitlines(1),
...              'ore\ntree\nemu\n'.splitlines(1))
>>> print ''.join(diff),
- one
?  ^
+ ore
?  ^
```

So the `^` symbol is simply pointing to where the differences are.

Comment: Does the comparison happen line by line? What if the 2 lines are entirely different?

Comment: @RowanaRavenclaw. Well, it's easy enough to find out if you just try it for yourself ;-) But anyway, it seems only relatively small differences are highlighted. Personally, I much prefer the format of [unified_diff](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff), which doesn't display the `?` lines. I think it's only `ndiff` that adds them.